# MySQL where datediff equals to some value

Tags: mysql

My use case is something like this,
I have a table called `User_packages` there I have a column called `arrival_date`.

What I want is get to get this

**arrival_date - CURRENT_DATE() = 7**

I want to get the days where the difference between arrival_date and the CURRENT_DATE() is equals to 7.

I write this query but this has syntax error

SELECT * FROM booking_widget.User_packages where datediff(current_date()-arrival_date) = 7;

How do I achieve this using MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

Use PROPRER `DATEDIFF` function,

Like.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,arrival_date,CURRENT_DATE())
```

Your Query is

```
SELECT *,DATEDIFF(DAY,arrival_date,CURRENT_DATE()) FROM booking_widget.User_packages where DATEDIFF(DAY,arrival_date,CURRENT_DATE()) = 7;
```

Comment: This is not how the MySQL [`DATEDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function works

Answer (score 0):

The [`DATEDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function itself computes a difference, so you only need to pass the two dates whose difference you want.

```
SELECT *
FROM booking_widget.User_packages
WHERE DATEDIFF(arrival_date, CURRENT_DATE()) = 7;
```

Note that `DATEDIFF(d1, d2)` returns a positive number when `d1` is greater than `d2`, so you probably want to pass the arrival date as the first parameter if you expect it to be in the future.

Comment: same/similar. less than 2 seconds apart... 03:50:57 -v- 03:52:03 , is that a crime?

Comment: Some people can drink half a beer in 2 seconds :P

Comment: :) I can chug quite a bit in 1:06

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM booking_widget.User_packages 
where datediff(current_date(),arrival_date) = 7;
```

the `datediff()` performs the subtraction, so you pass the 2 dates as parameters [see datediff](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

> DATEDIFF(expr1,expr2)
>   returns expr1 − expr2 expressed as a value in
>   days

So the order of the dates is important to return a positive number, e.g.

```
SELECT * 
FROM booking_widget.User_packages 
where datediff(arrival_date,current_date()) = 7;
```

or, if the order isn't important to you, but the the gap value is, include `abs()`

```
SELECT * 
FROM booking_widget.User_packages 
where abs(datediff(arrival_date,current_date())) = 7;
```